# pyinstaller problemas al empaquetar libreria bitcoinlib

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Poseo el siguiente script que usa la librería `bitcoinlib`:

```
from bitcoinlib.mnemonic import Mnemonic
from bitcoinlib.wallets import Wallet
import bitcoinlib

try:
    passphrase = Mnemonic().generate()
    print(passphrase)

    nameWalletP2SH="".join(passphrase.split()) + "P2SH"
    bitcoinlib.wallets.wallet_delete_if_exists(nameWalletP2SH)
    P2SH = Wallet.create(nameWalletP2SH,keys=passphrase, network='bitcoin',witness_type='p2sh-segwit')
    WalletKeys = (P2SH.get_keys(number_of_keys=1))
    P2SHAddress=P2SH.get_key().address
    balanceps2hsegwit=P2SH.balance()

    print(P2SHAddress)
    print(balanceps2hsegwit)
    input('presione enter para finalizar: ')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    input('error: ')
```

la misma funciona excelente, sin mas problemas. El problema viene cuando quiero compilarla, pasarla a un **.exe**, el mismo me da el error de que no encuentra la librería `bitcoinlib` ó sencillamente no me da salida alguna en la consola, incluí una pausa para terminar el programa, así asegurándome de ver el resultado en consola, pero se cierra.

Compilación:

```
pyinstaller --uac-admin --onefile "C:\Users\NiGaN\Desktop\cryptotest.py"
```

la misma me genera los siguientes `WARNINGS`

```
35364 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
35364 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
35364 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
```